# Need streamread to read the same number of characters each time

Tags: vb.net, streamreader, ebcdic

I am working with a legacy text file that is in EBCDIC on an IBM mainframe.  I have downloaded the file from the mainframe to my PC. The file contains packed data. I am working with VB.net. The issue is that some of the pack data's characters show as carriage return (H"0D") causing the line to be split by stream reader.  How do I get streamreader to read the fixed length records each time?

Comment: [BinaryReader.ReadBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) and [How to: Read and Write to a Newly Created Data File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b93480(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: need new users to read [ask], take the [tour] and expend some effort on their own problem